# O que faz uma linguagem ser considerada de baixo/alto nível?

Tags: característica-linguagem, teoria-da-computação

O que faz uma linguagem ser considerada de alto nível e outras de baixo nível?

Comment: Assembly é demasiadamente de alto nível, se comparado com código binário. :p

Comment: Acho que nem tanto. O Assembler (montador), basicamente, só vai substituir palavras em Assembly (linguagem) por endereços de memória e códigos em binário. Isto faz do Assembly apenas uma outra forma mais legível, uma forma de ver números binários em uma linguagem compreensível a humanos.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

O "nível" nesse contexto pode ser entendido como o nível de detalhamento do algoritmo para que ele execute uma determinada tarefa.

Fazendo uma analogia, considere que você pronunciou a seguinte frase para um colega seu de classe:

> (Por favor,) pegue a minha borracha que caiu no chão.

Vamos assumir por hora que esse pode ser considerado como um comando de altíssimo nível. Você não precisou digitá-lo em lugar nenhum, se você cometer algum erro de Português nele ainda assim tem chances de ser compreendido corretamente pelo receptor, enfim, você não precisou dar muitos detalhes para a execução de uma tarefa relativamente complexa (você vai entender por que estou dizendo que a tarefa é complexa olhando logo mais abaixo).

Se ao invés do seu colega, você falar isso para o seu computador, pode ter certeza, nada ele fará. Quando você passou o comando para uma pessoa, ela traduziu essa única frase em inúmeros comandos super detalhados que estão relacionados com estender e flexionar seus inúmeros músculos, o equilíbrio do seu corpo, respiração, dentre inúmeras outras coisas que você não precisa falar para ela pois esses detalhes do funcionamento do corpo dela não precisam ser passados no seu comando para que a pessoa o execute. Por exemplo, ninguém vai deixar de respirar ao abaixar para pegar uma borracha e alegar:

> Você não deixou claro que eu deveria continuar respirando enquanto eu pegava a borracha, por isso achei que eu deveria parar de respirar enquanto eu não terminava a tarefa que você me passou.

Supondo agora que você construiu um robô que possui uma anatomia que se assemelha ao do ser humano, porém ele não possui o cérebro de um ser humano, e que ele tem a capacidade de entender as palavras que você pronuncia e responder a elas através de ações, entretanto a quantidade de palavras que ele é capaz de entender são muito limitadas assim como as ações que ele é capaz de executar. Suponha que as ações que ele pode executar são coisas do tipo: "levante o braço", "abaixe o braço", "ande por 5 metros", e coisas desse tipo, imagine que agora uma pessoa quer falar para esse robô se abaixar para pegar uma borracha que caiu no chão, o robô não sabe o que é "borracha", tampouco sabe o que é "cair". Logo, não se pode esperar que passar para o robô o mesmo comando que foi passado para o ser humano e esperar que ele complete a tarefa assim como o humano foi capaz, nesse caso, os comandos deveriam ser um nível de detalhamento muito maior, como por exemplo:

```
* Gire seu corpo 14° para a esquerda;  
* Ande por 112mm;  
* Incline seu corpo 60° para a frente;  
* Dobre o seu joelho em 15º;  
* Estenda seu braço deixando-o perpendicular ao plano;  
* Feche a ponta dos dedos até que se faça contato com um objeto;
* Volte o seu tronco para a posição vertical;  
* Desdobre seu joelho;  
* Gire o seu corpo 90° para a direita;  
* Ande por 40mm;  
* Abra a mão.
```

E você corre o risco de ter errado em algum número de todo esse algoritmo que fará com que o seu robô pegue o pé do seu colega ao invés de pegar a borracha, ou que ele caia no chão ao dobrar o joelho pois você não calculou direito o ângulo que deveria ter sido passado para ele.

Logo, comparativamente, a linguagem usada com o ser humano foi de muito mais alto nível que a linguagem usada com o robô, pois não foi necessário passar inúmeros detalhes da implementação para que ele concluísse a tarefa. Isso não quer dizer que a linguagem utilizada com o robô **é** de baixo nível, ela só é de **mais** baixo nível que a linguagem usada com o ser humano. Por isso é difícil afirmar o que é uma linguagem de baixo e alto nível já que isso depende dos parâmetros que são usados naquele momento, se os parâmetros mudam a classificação do alto e do baixo nível também muda.

Código de máquina pode ser considerado baixíssimo nível, isso é claro se você não considerar a possibilidade de escrever um código com uma agulha magnetizada mudando os bits no seu HD ;)

E Java pode ser considerado de alto nível, até você parar para pensar que alto nível na verdade é o comando que o cliente passou para o programador:

> Quero um sistema que faça isso, isso e aquilo.

E isso pode ainda não ser considerado tão alto nível, caso existisse a possibilidade do programador saber o que o cliente precisa de apenas olhar para ele (sonho :P).

## E como o mundo acadêmico define o "nível"?

Ao invés de apenas contar a história de um robô que se parecia com uma pessoa, resolvi recolher alguns fragmentos de livros, artigos, dentre outros para comparar com o que eu afirmei e verificar se está de acordo com o que esses autores afirmam em suas obras. O que eu achei durante minha pesquisa foi que ao tentarem dar uma classificação do "nível" de uma linguagem os autores acabaram sendo por demais superficiais ou até mesmo contraditórios. Vejamos abaixo.

No prefácio da primeira edição, de 1978, do livro [**Kernighan, Brian W., and Dennis M. Ritchie. The C programming language. Vol. 2. Englewood Cliffs: prentice-Hall, 1988.**](http://alvand.basu.ac.ir/%7Edezfoulian/files/Programming/Prentice%20Hall%20-%20The%20C%20Programming%20Language-%20Brian%20W.%20Kernighan,%20Dennis%20M.%20Ritchie,%202nd%20ed.,%20ISBN%20.pdf), tem o seguinte texto:

> C is a general-purpose programming language with features economy of expression, modern flow control and data structures, and a rich set of operators. C is not a "very high level" language, nor a "big" one, and is not specialized to any particular area of application. [...]

Em tradução livre:

> C é uma linguagem de programação de propósito geral com a caracterização de economia de expressão, moderno controle de fluxo e estruturas de dados, e um rico conjunto de operadores. **C não é uma linguagem "muito alto nível"**, nem "grande", e não é especializada em nenhuma área em particular de aplicação. [...]

Ao afirmar que ela não é "muito alto nível" eu tiro por conclusão que ela é alto nível, mas não muito... seja lá o quanto o autor considera "muito" para esse caso. É no mínimo uma definição vaga, mas continuemos.

Ainda no mesmo livro, na introdução, 3 páginas depois, o autor afirma:

> C is a relatively "low-level" language. This characterization is not pejorative; it simply means that C deals with the same sort of objects that most computers do. [...]

Em tradução livre:

> **C é relativamente uma linguagem de "baixo-nível"**. Essa caracterização não é pejorativa; isso simplesmente significa que o C lida com os mesmo tipos de objetos que a maioria dos computadores. [...]

Não sei vocês, mas eu fiquei confuso, pois agora a linguagem foi dada como "baixo nível".

Vale a pena ressaltar que o autor desse livro é ninguém menos do que Dennis Ritchie, o criador da linguagem C. Já o livro em questão é famoso por ter dado a vida a linguagem C, pois até o seu lançamento a linguagem não era muito difundida, ele foi o maior divisor de águas da história da linguagem C. Entrentato, nem por isso foi possível encontrar nele uma resposta objetiva sobre o nível da linguagem C.

Outro livro que teve uma grande importância na história do C, [**Koenig, Andrew. C traps and pitfalls. AT and T Bell Laboratories. Computing Science, 1986.**](http://people.clarkson.edu/%7Ejsearlem/cs241/sp15/references/CTrapsAndPitfalls.pdf) podemos encontrar nas referências do livro:

> The C Programming Language (Kernighan and Ritchie, Prentice-Hall 1978) is the definitive work on C. It contains both an excellent tutorial, aimed at people who are already familiar with other high-level languages, and a reference manual that describes the entire language succinctly. While the language has expanded slightly since 1978, this book is still the last word on most subjects. [...]

Em tradução livre:

> O livro C Programming Language (Kernighan and Ritchie, Prentice-Hall 1978) é o trabalho definitivo em C. Ele contém tanto um excelente tutorial, destinados para aquelas pessoas que já são familiares com **outras linguagens de alto nível**, e um manual de referência que descreve a linguagem inteira sucintamente. Enquanto a linguagem expandiu desde 1978, esse livro ainda é a última palavra na maioria dos assuntos. [...]

Mais uma vez a linguagem C foi definida como sendo de alto nível.

Não está muito complicado ainda? Que tal então darmos uma olhada no texto de [**uma parte de uma dissertação de mestrado da Universidade Federal do Rio Grande do Sul**](http://www.ufrgs.br/engcart/PDASR/linguagens.html) :

> Por ser uma **linguagem de médio nível**, o algoritmo em C torna-se mais complexo do que o mesmo algoritmo feito no PHP (alto nível), por exemplo. Em compensação, o programador possui um número de recursos muito maior e pode controlar com mais segurança as operações que necessita processar.

Que dá uma nova classificação para o C que até agora não tínhamos visto: Médio nível `:-/`

O Wikipedia por sua vez afirma algo de forma clara e que as citações acima somente levam a crer que ele está coberto de razão, ao descrever [**o significado relativo do nível das linguagens de programação**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language) :

> The terms high-level and low-level are inherently relative. Some decades ago, the C language, and similar languages, were most often considered "high-level", as it supported concepts such as expression evaluation, parameterised recursive functions, and data types and structures, while assembly language was considered "low-level". Today, many programmers might refer to C as low-level, as it lacks a large runtime-system (no garbage collection, etc.), basically supports only scalar operations, and provides direct memory addressing. It, therefore, readily blends with assembly language and the machine level of CPUs and microcontrollers.
>
> Assembly language may itself be regarded as a higher level (but often still one-to-one if used without macros) representation of machine code, as it supports concepts such as constants and (limited) expressions, sometimes even variables, procedures, and data structures. Machine code, in its turn, is inherently at a slightly higher level than the microcode or micro-operations used internally in many processors.

Em tradução livre:

> Os termos alto nível e baixo nível são inerentemente relativos. Algumas décadas atrás, a linguagem C, e linguagens similares, eram frequentemente consideradas "alto nível", por elas suportarem conceitos como análise de expressões, funções recursivas parametrizadas, tipo de dados e estruturas, enquanto o assembly era considerado "baixo nível". Hoje, muitos programadores podem se referir ao C como uma linguagem de baixo nível, por faltar-lhe um grande sistema de *runtime* (sem garbage collection, etc.), basicamente suporta apenas operações escalares, e fornece acesso direto ao endereçamento de memória. Isso, com certeza, prontamente combina com a linguagem assembly e o nível de máquina das CPUs e micro controladores.
>
> A linguagem assembly mesmo pode ser consideradas linguagens de alto nível (mas geralmente ainda um-para-um se usado sem macros) de representação de código de máquina, por ela suportar conceitos como constantes e expressões (limitadas), as vezes até variáveis, procedimento, e estrutura de dados. Código de máquina, por sua vez, é inerentemente levemente mais alto nível que o micro código ou micro operações usadas internamente em muito processadores.

Em busca de uma definição clara e sucinta do que é alto e baixo nível, e em qual nível a linguagem C se encaixa, isso foi o que eu encontrei.

Para mim, esses trechos acima apenas deixam claro o que já foi dito nas respostas e nos comentários (não somente de minha autoria) aqui desse tópico: A classificação do nível de uma determinada linguagem muda conforme novas necessidades surgem e novas tecnologias também, então é impossível determinar de forma definitiva qual é o nível de uma linguagem, apenas conseguimos dizer que o nível é mais alto ou mais baixo ao compararmos com um determinado parâmetro.

<sub>Obs: Os links dos livros foram retirados do [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com.br), cujo seus [Termos se Serviço](https://www.google.com.br/intl/pt-BR/policies/terms/regional.html) deixam claro que eles respeitam os direitos autorais e se compromete a publicar o que eles têm permissão.</sub>

Comment: Créditos da agulha magnetizada para o OnoSendai que mandou o seguinte quadrinho no chat esses dias: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20700984#20700984 Mais baixo que a agulha magnetizada apenas as borboletas do quadrinho :)

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1 pela didática e pela descontração. :D

Comment: @Math - *Dammit*, EMacs. ;)

Comment: em suma: baixo nível (próximo a linguagem de máquina), alto nível (próximo a linguagem humana)

Answer (score 55):

## Uma imagem vale mais do que mil palavras

[image: Baixo e alto nível]

## Abstração computacional

Pensando numa abordagem para diferenciar linguagens de alto e baixo nível do ponto de vista de quem está programando, *o nível da linguagem é proporcional ao quanto você gasta pensando em resolver o seu problema (alto nível) ou em resolver problemas relacionados aos cálculos computacionais (baixo nível)*.

Por exemplo, considere os "comandos" a seguir:

> 1. Mova o texto "ABC" para a posição de memória 123, copie todos os caracteres para o fluxo aberto que aponta para a posição 456 do disco.
> 2. Gravar o texto "ABC" no arquivo "doc.txt"
> 3. Atualize o nome do cliente com o valor "João"

O item #1 é certamente o que possui mais baixo nível. Em relação a ele, o item #2 é de mais alto nível.

Porém, temos o item #3, que é de mais alto nível que todos. Em relação a ele, o item #2 é de mais baixo nível.

## Quantidade de camadas de abstração

Desde que os computadores surgiram há um esforço para tornar a sua programação mais fácil. Isso foi feito criando-se novas linguagens e compiladores mais avançados, assim como através de macros, métodos ou objetos que abstraem e automatizam certas tarefas.

Porém, cada vez que adicionamos uma dessas "facilidades", aumentamos a quantidade de camadas de abstração ou indireção em relação à computação binária.

Por exemplo:

1. **Assembly** é uma linguagem que se mapeia praticamente direto para código de máquina, mas ainda assim o programa é escrito em texto antes de ser convertido em binário. Em geral, cada comando assembly consiste em uma instrução ao processador.
2. **C** é uma linguagem de mais alto nível, onde cada comando é traduzido pelo compilador geralmente em várias instruções Assembly (ainda que em memória) antes de realmente gerar código binário.
3. **Java** e **.NET** são linguagens ainda de mais alto nível porque cada comando gera uma ou mais instruções de máquinas virtuais, que não é o mesmo que linguagem de máquina. Cada instrução dessas máquinas virtuais precisa ser traduzida, em tempo de execução, para um conjunto de instruções de máquina correspondente à arquitetura da CPU onde o programa está rodando.
4. No **PHP**, enquanto linguagem interpretada, cada comando é processado por código previamente compilado em C, geralmente levando à execução de vários trechos de código equivalentes a várias funções C que são mapeadas para inúmeras instruções de máquina.

Vale notar que, em geral, a quantidade de níveis de abstração é proporcional ao quanto o programador fica "longe" do hardware, mas nem sempre isso é diretamente proporcional.

## Suba o nível

Independente da linguagem, programadores devem programar em alto nível sempre que possível.

Mesmo que sua plataforma de desenvolvimento permita conversar diretamente com o *hardware*, a fim de manter a sanidade, um bom programador irá abstrair toda essa complexidade em rotinas de mais alto nível conforme as capacidades da linguagem (funções, método, objetos, módulos, etc.).

Imagine o seguinte código:

```
notaFiscal = ler_arquivo_nota_fiscal(caminho);
validar_nota_fiscal(notaFiscal);
salvar_nova_fiscal(notaFiscal);
```

Exceto pelo estilo de codificação, seja Java ou JavaScript, C ou C#, ShellScript ou PHP, qualquer um pode entender o que o código acima faz e implementar os detalhes nas respectivas rotinas.

No fim das contas, não é porque alguém programa em C que necessariamente precisa estar sempre codificando em baixo nível.

## Considerações

Não é possível afirmar absolutamente que uma dada linguagem é de alto ou baixo nível.

O que poderíamos dizer é que todas as linguagens de programação são de mais alto nível em relação ao código binário (desde que seja humanamente possível ler o código, obviamente).

Além disso, poderíamos ainda afirmar que uma linguagem `X` é de mais alto ou mais baixo nível em relação à alguma outra linguagem `Y` considerando o aspecto `Z`.

Por fim, dentro de uma mesma linguagem, é possível programar em diferentes níveis de abstração. Bons programadores irão subir o nível sempre que possível tanto para aumentar a produtividade quanto para uma melhor qualidade do código.

Comment: Sim, talvez antigamente quando o C foi criado ele devia ser considerado sem dúvidas de alto nível em relação a Assembly

Comment: Como eu posso fazer uma macro no Assembly para expressar algo como na primeira forma então um Assembly que aceite macros pode ser considerada de alto nível?

Comment: @bigown Uma macro é uma abstração em mais alto nível de um conjunto de instruções de mais baixo nível. Pensando bem, um compilador C, por exemplo, não faz basicamente a mesma coisa se pensarmos em cada comando de uma linguagem de alto nível como uma macro?

Comment: @bigown Na minha opinião existem várias linguagens assembly em níveis diferentes mas ainda assim muito próximos. Entretanto considerando o espectro de todas as linguagens continua sendo baixo nível.

Comment: Justamente esta é a questão. Não dá para definir muito bem o que é alto e o que é baixo nível. Toda vez que alguém tenta pegar um aspecto e dizer que aquilo define se é alto nível ou não, aparece uma forma de analisar a mesma coisa mostrando o contrário. Por isto cada um acha uma coisa sobre C.

Comment: @bigown Concordo. Minha resposta inicial era apenas um esboço mental. Dei uma melhorada agora para deixar esse ponto claro.

Comment: Foi colocado outro ponto importante, uma linguagem pode ter uma abstração absurda e não ser legível, e aí? Esta definição é complicada e acho que por isto ninguém se arriscou cravá-la ou se alguém o fez, não foi levado à sério. Acho que a pergunta serviu mais para esclarecer esta dificuldade de classificação e dar uma parâmetro geral de avaliação.

Comment: +1 só pela imagem :)

Answer (score 43):

Eu já vi diversas definições mas desconheço uma que seja universalmente aceita como correta e precisa. Existem algumas pessoas com opiniões sobre o assunto.

Genericamente dá para dizer que linguagens de alto nível são aquelas que fornecem maior nível de abstração e as de baixo nível são as que fornecem um menor nível, portanto são mais concretas.

Outra forma de explicar é dizer que as linguagens de alto nível são aquelas que estão mais próximas do entendimento humano e as de baixo nível estão mais próximas da operação concreta da máquina.

As linguagens de alto nível são mais expressivas, ou seja, você diz melhor qual a intenção do algoritmo. As outras dizem mais o que fazer sem se preocupar em deixar claro qual é a intenção.

Certamente a falta de sintaxe com melhores construções para expressar de forma intuitiva o que está querendo fazer, de forma estruturada torna uma linguagem de mais baixo nível. Estas linguagens não conseguem definir bem o problema como ele realmente é. Elas se preocupam muito com o mecanismo para resolver o problema e menos com o conceito dele.

Também é certo que há mais controle do que a máquina deve executar em linguagens de baixo nível.

Então a classificação se daria pela distância que ela tem do trabalho do hardware. Em geral as linguagens de alto nível dificultam ou mesmo proíbem o acesso direto ao hardware, que é o oposto do que fazem as linguagens de baixo nível. Mas não é só o acesso que conta, é a forma como este acesso é feito. As linguagens de alto nível não requerem conhecimento profundo sobre o funcionamento do *hardware*.

Não sei se é possível dar uma definição mais específica que isto sem entrar em polêmica. Pior ainda é tentar classificar linguagens. Aí a polêmica é maior por falta de uma definição formal. Não é fácil para traçar uma linha e dizer isto é alto ou baixo nível. Dá para fazer uma relação de grandeza, indicar que uma linguagem é mais alto nível que outra. É claro que todo mundo concorda que linguagem de máquina é baixo nível e linguagem de *script* é alto nível. Há tantas controvérsias, tanto que criaram o médio nível e o muito alto nível para classificar algumas linguagens. Que nível é C? Já ouvi pelo menos três níveis e se eu disser que concordo com um deles será apenas minha opinião. A não ser que alguém me mostre algum estudo confiável e validado que deixe claro e de forma inconteste como classificar uma linguagem. É possível fazer isto, só não acho que tenha uma definição formal aceitável.

Algumas pessoas costumam dizer que linguagens de alto nível são mais fáceis de aprender e usar. Eu não concordo totalmente com isto. Aprender costuma ser mais difícil, pelo menos pra mim. De usar depende do problema que está sendo resolvido. Por isto não acho uma boa forma de classificar.

Também dizem sobre a independência da execução em qualquer máquina como característica das linguagens de alto nível. Mas não me parece que isto se aplique em 100% dos casos.

A velocidade de execução também parece ser um efeito colateral apenas.

A Wikipedia tem definições extensas sobre o que é linguagem de [alto nível](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language) e de [baixo nível](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language). Não vejo estas definições sendo aceitam por todos.

Mas acho pior quando tentam classificar as linguagens por gerações. A aplicação do conceito já é errada.

Gosto da definição do Alan Perlis em seus famosos [epigramas da programação](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/perlis-alan/quotes.html), principalmente:

> Uma linguagem de programação é de baixo nível quando seus programas requerem atenção aos aspectos irrelevantes (ao domínio)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que será que tem errado na pergunta para receber -1. Tem dia que eu sou escolhido para receber negativos.

Comment: só um detalhes "O que será que tem errado na PERGUNTA para receber -1" ???? Nada ué...srsrsr toma +1 já que gostei do comentário

Answer (score 29):

A linguagem de baixo nível trabalha mais diretamente com o hardware, é uma linguagem mais próxima da linguagem de máquina. Assembly é um exemplo de linguagem de baixo nível.

Já uma linguagem de alto nível permite que se trabalhe sem precisar definir questões mais relativas ao hardware. É mais próxima da linguagem humana. Um exemplo de linguagem de alto nível é Java.

Linguagens de alto nível tendem a ser mais rápidas para programar, no entanto tem um desempenho inferior no tempo de execução. Já linguagens de baixo nível tendem a exigir um trabalho mais dispendioso, no entanto, permitem a criação de programas mais leves e rápidos.

Answer (score 25):

Minha opinião é que tem a ver com a forma que os recursos da linguagem são feitos. A mais baixo nível repassa fielmente os recursos da máquina (mesmo que seja uma máquina virtual). Enquanto as mais alto nível agregam recursos baseados em outros recursos mais fundamentais.

Por exemplo:

- `if/else` e `while` são mais alto nível que um `if + goto`;
- `if + goto` é mais alto nível que `cmp`, `jnz`, `je`, `jle`, `jz`, `jmp` (instruções assembly);
- `jle` (uma instrução assembly) é mais alto nível que `7E xx` (JLE short), `0F 8E xx xx` (JLE near 32 bits mode), `0F 8E xx xx xx xx` (JLE near 64 bits mode). Note que o JLE do assembly pode ser compilado para 3 instruções de máquina, dependendo do operando, e do modo de operação do processador (32-bits ou 64-bits).

Como um recurso é feito a partir do outro, o nível vai subindo, como se fosse uma escada. Eu acho que é daí que veio a analogia de níveis baixo e alto.

Eu sei que fui muito opinativo, se alguém achar que faltou objetividade me fale, que eu tento melhorar.

Comment: se eu tivesse lido sua resposta primeiro, nem teria escrito a minha rsrsr, p/ mim é isso ai mesmo.

Comment: Que isso amigo... não tem problema. Essa resposta é meio difícil de ver mesmo, afinal estou rodeado de titans aqui no SOPT. =D

Answer (score 20):

Uma linguagem de baixo nível é a que não necessita de um interpretador que converta o código desenvolvido para linguagem máquina (Ex. C / Assembly)

Uma linguagem de Alto Nível é toda a linguagem, não compilada que necessita de um interpretador ou pré-interpretador, de forma a ser convertida em linguagem máquina, de forma a ser compreendida e executada pelo *hardware* (Ex. Processador / Memória).

Poderemos dizer então, que as grandes diferenças entre as Linguagens de Alto Nível e Baixo Nível, são as seguintes:

**Linguagens de alto nível** ( Python, Java )

- Fornecem uma gestão automática de memória onde o programador não tem nenhum control sobre como a memória é alocada e recuperada.
- A recolha de do "lixo" gerado pela gestão automática do interpretador, requer armazenamento físico.

**Linguagens de baixo nível** ( C , Assembly )

- O *workflow* de processos é gerido pelo código desenvolvido, dando ao programador total liberdade da gestão dos recursos disponíveis do hardware.
- todos os recursos de memória são geridos pelo programador e pelo programa desenvolvido.

Mais informações, consultar:

- Massachusetts Institute of Technology: [Efficient Implementation of High-Level Languages on
  User-Level Communication Architectures](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-616.pdf)
- University of Virginia: [Low-Level Programming - Class 9](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CHMQFjAJ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.virginia.edu%2F~evans%2Fcs216%2Fclasses%2Flecture9.ppt&ei=oVwoVeX2O4btUqHxgJgG&usg=AFQjCNGJSMcpuv7yDMg_BoIoi_Ex-X5JaA&sig2=m7O3dM-dF1XomWMQ1ZlZTw)

Comment: Apesar de aceita como resposta, a definição está completamente equivocada.  
Linguagens de baixo nível só existem duas: Assembly e código de máquina.  
Quem programa em Assembly sabe que uma instrução de Assembly equivale a uma instrução em código de máquina, e é por isso que é considerada baixo-nível.  
Por outro lado, linguagens de alto nível como C não tem essa proporção de 1 por 1 como Assembly. Toda uma estrutura por baixo do código em C é gerada pelo compilador, inserindo muitas instruções de máquina para uma única instrução feita pelo programador. (só pra avisar para os "Googleiros")

Answer (score 16):

O que faz uma linguagem ser de Baixo/Alto nível é o nível de abstração delas, quanto mais próximo do hardware (próximo mesmo, ao ponto de ser necessário conhecimento sobre o hardware onde será implementado e instalado) mais baixo nível ela será (menor será a legibilidade ao ponte de se usar mnemônicos e produtividade já que terá de se escrever varias instruções pequenas (naturalmente são mais granularizadas) para obter um determinado resultado) e quanto mais alto o nível mais próximo ela tende a ser parecida com a linguagem natural, permitem que algoritmos sejam expressos em um nível e estilo de escrita fácil para leitura e compreensão, possuem características de portabilidade já que podem ser transferidas de uma máquina para outra. abaixo uma imagem explicativa rudimentar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguns exemplos de linguagem para cada tipo de linguagem:

**Linguagem de maquina e de assembly:** Linguagens que dependem da arquitetura da máquina (Linguagem de montagem é uma representação simbólica da linguagem de máquina associada).

**Linguagens de Médio nível:** Apesar de muitos não aceitarem este termo, `C` é classificada como uma linguagem de médio nível, porque ela pode, por exemplo, acessar os registros do sistema ou trabalhar com endereços de memória, que são características de linguagens de baixo nível, e ao mesmo realizar operações de alto nível.

**Linguagens de Alto nível:** Java, PHP, C# e muitas outras.

**Linguagens declarativas** (Linguagens expressivas como a linguagem oral
expressam o que fazer ao invés de como fazer, pode conter: programação funcional, programação lógica ou programação restritiva): `Haskell` (funcional) e `Prolog`(lógica).

Um adendo: As linguagens podem ser divididas em gerações também:

- Primeira geração: Linguagem máquina.
- Segunda geração: Criaram-se as primeiras linguagens assembler.
- Terceira geração: Criam-se as primeiras linguagens de alto nível.
  Ex: C*, Pascal, Cobol…
- Quarta    geração: São linguagens capazes de gerar código por si só,
  são os    chamados RAD, com o qual pode-se realizar aplicações sem
  ser um    expert na linguagem. Aqui também se encontram as linguagens
  orientadas a objetos, tornando possível a reutilização de partes do
  código para outros programas. Ex: Visual, Natural Adabes…
- Quinta    geração: Aqui se encontram as linguagens orientadas à
  inteligência    artificial. Estas linguagens ainda estão pouco
  desenvolvidas. Ex:    LISP

Outro adendo a pergunta (um pouco fora do escopo): Há frameworks de linguagens de alto nível que como o `Rails` e `Grails` que aumentam e muito a produtividade do desenvolvedor.

Answer (score 14):

**Linguagem de programação de alto nível** é como se chama, na Ciência da Computação de linguagens de programação, uma linguagem com um nível de abstração relativamente elevado, longe do código de máquina e mais próximo à linguagem humana. Desse modo, as linguagens de alto nível não estão diretamente relacionadas à arquitetura do computador. O programador de uma linguagem de alto nível não precisa conhecer características do processador, como instruções e registradores.

**Linguagem de programação de baixo nível** trata-se de uma linguagem de programação que compreende as características da arquitetura do computador. Assim, utiliza somente instruções do processador, para isso é necessário conhecer os registradores da máquina. Nesse sentido, as linguagens de baixo nível estão diretamente relacionadas com a arquitetura do computador. Um exemplo é a linguagem Assembly (não Assembler) que trabalha diretamente com os registradores do processador, manipulando dados

Answer (score 13):

Simplificando...

**Alto Nível**: Mais longe da linguagem de máquina.

**Baixo Nível**: Mais próximo da linguagem de máquina.

**Linguagem de máquina** = Binário... Zero (0) e Um (1) = 11001100011

Logo: Quanto mais baixo nível você programa, mais complicado é o processo e quanto mais alto nível é mais fácil.

**Observação**: Já ouviu falar de portugol? É uma linguagem em português, utilizada para aprender Lógica de Programação. É considerada uma linguagem de alto nível, pois é fácil a interpretação dos códigos.

Answer (score 12):

Eu vou ser curto para não alongar como os demais, o código que você escreveu é para manipular diretamente o hardware? ex: programação de driver de um determinado equipamento, então você irá usar uma linguagem de baixo nível, o nível é baixo então é próximo do hardware.

Se você escreveu um código-fonte, que você não sabe de onde vem algumas coisas ex: a janela/tela do sistema que você codificou já vem pronta - ou você utilizou API, ou plugin, já tem um monte de código por "baixo" do que você programou, então você está programando em alto nível.

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que as polêmicas e discordâncias são devido ao termo utilizado "low level " e "high level".  Acho que um termo mais apropriado poderia ser "low layer" e "high layer" ou seja, "baixa camada" e "alta camada". Mas enfim, pelo que sempre entendi, as linguagens de baixo nível são as que lidam diretamente com o hardware. Um exemplo é o Assembly (Assembler).

Há um certa confusão também sobre "o que é comunicar-se diretamente com o hardware" pois atualmente muitos dispositivos e componentes de hardware oferecem APIs de comunicação, por meio da qual, linguagens de alto nível conseguem se comunicar com o hardware. Nesses casos não há comunicação direta com o hardware pois quem faz isso é o compilador da linguagem interna da API, normalmente escrita em Assembly.

Answer (score 4):

A *linguagem de alto nível* tem um nível de abstração mais elevado, tornando ela mais parecida com a linguagem humana e deixando-a mais distante do código de máquina. A *linguagem de baixo nível* é mais parecida como código de máquina e utiliza somente instruções do processador, sendo necessário conhecer os registradores da máquina.

Answer (score 2):

A classificação binária, Alto Nível x Baixo Nível, é extremamente simplista e não deveria mais ser utilizada. Ou, no mínimo, ser utilizada apenas quando acompanhada de uma explicação mais detalhada sobre o contexto em que se aplica - devendo ser, sempre, relativizada.

Pode-se apenas dizer que, sobre determinados parâmetros de comparação(explícitos), o software desenvolvido com a linguagem A tem nível de abstração mais alto que o software desenvolvido com a linguagem B.

Vamos a um exemplo. Se eu pedir para fazer um software específico, um software que lide com o ensino dos diferentes tipos de números usados pela matemática. Este software será de mais alto nível numa linguagem que tenha estes diferentes números internamente e será de mais baixo nível numa linguagem que não tenha, pois a mesma terá um trabalho enorme para construir estes conceitos, mesmo que supostamente seja de mais alto nível.
Ou seja, existe uma correlação entre o problema e a solução.
É mais fácil pregar um prego grande com um martelo grande, e um prego pequeno com um martelo pequeno. E não faz sentido em falar que um martelo é de baixo nível e outro de alto nível.

Ou seja, problemas de mais alto nível serão mais facilmente modelados em linguagens de mais alto nível. Já problemas de mais baixo nível serão mais facilmente modelados em linguagens de baixo nível.

Também não faz sentido falar que é de mais alto nível porque usa termos previamente conhecidos. Exemplo:
Imprimir("5");
não é mais alto nível que:
Print("5");
Apenas porque a primeira usa palavras que conheço previamente (português).
Eu por exemplo não vejo diferenças para:
cout << "5";
Inclusive, para mim, o indicador de redirecionamento << facilita o entendimento.
É mais abstrato e se aplica a diferentes tipos de objetos.

Enfim, acho que o uso de termos simplistas que num primeiro momento facilitam a compreensão e aprendizado, rapidamente se tornam um problema, pois nem todos conseguem lidar/compreender que aquele uso era apenas para um entendimento inicial.

Para piorar, muitos professores "+práticos" acabam suprimindo os conceitos em favor de chegar mais rápido a prática, e os alunos acabam aprendendo de forma superficial (e muitas vezes errada) os conceitos de base. Acabam desenvolvendo diversos vícios e equívocos, difíceis de serem corrigidos.