# Por que a linguagem C é considerada como uma linguagem de médio nível?

Tags: c, característica-linguagem

A linguagem de programação C é considerada uma linguagem de nível médio. Por que?

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57309/o-que-faz-uma-linguagem-ser-considerada-de-baixo-alto-n%c3%advel/57314#57314

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que faz uma linguagem ser considerada de baixo/alto nível?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57309/o-que-faz-uma-linguagem-ser-considerada-de-baixo-alto-n%c3%advel)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 7):

Dê uma referência que indique que isso é verdade. E defina o que é médio nível.

## Não existe nível de linguagem

Essa coisa de nível de linguagem é complicada e há controvérsias do que é baixo ou alto nível, piorou tentar achar um limite do que é médio nível.

Alguém pode dizer que é, mas não é fácil dizer porque é, o que faz a linguagem sair de um dos dois extremos e ser médio nível.

As pessoas que eu conheço tratam C como linguagem de alto nível, ainda que esse nível não seja tão alto assim.

Então por não ser tão alto alguém quer dizer que ela é de médio nível.

Pela definição que eu uso as linguagens tem níveis mais baixos ou mais altos, mas dizer qual é esse nível exato é mais complicado. Não é como digital, é mais pra analógico, tem muitas gradações para criar marcas de parada.

#### Exemplos

Dentro disso é só claro como baixo nível o Assembly, a linguagem que você tem que dizer o que fazer diretamente para o processador fazer. Mesmo isso pode ser contestado porque diretamente só usando linguagem binária. No Assembly há uma relação um para um do que o processador fará, mas ainda haverá alguma tradução do escrito para o que o processador entende. Então algumas pessoas talvez digam que o Assembly é médio nível e baixo seria o binário, se é que médio nível existe. Não sei, não há uma formalização sobre o assunto.

C é uma linguagem de programação como outra qualquer que todos conhecem. A distância para C ou Python é muito menor do que as pessoas leigas acreditam.

De fato, C é mais baixo nível que Python, mas ainda é muito alto nível. C exige que você tome conta de determinadas questões que Python faz automático para você.

> A programming language is low level when its programs require
> attention to the irrelevant.
>
> -- Alan Perlis

Então quanto mais a linguagem exige você se preocupar com o irrelevante mais ela é de baixo nível, quanto mais automática ela é em pegar a intenção do que executar, ou seja, quanto mais expressiva ela é, mais alto nível ela é.

Não estou dizendo que essa é a melhor definição de todas, mas é uma boa.

Nesse critério C é um pouco mais baixo nível porque ela exige você dizer os tipos de dados, e gerenciar a memória. Além disso tem que usar *array* para qualquer coleção de dados sem ser muito específico, você não encapsula nada. Então, sim, isso não é lá muito alto nível.

Todas as outras linguagens poderiam ser um pouco mais alto nível, mas estão longe de um nível tão alto assim, o nível realmente alto exigiria que as linguagens fossem muito fluentes, que você dissesse de grosso modo e tudo aconteceria.

A diferença de nível entre C e Python é muito pequena. Dá para dizer que é médio nível por causa disso? Acho que não é o fim do mundo, mas eu acho que é complicado fazer tal afirmação, pra mim ela é alto nível, *pero no mucho*, só isso.

#### Wikipedia

Vejamos a Wikipedia, apesar que lá tem muita coisa errada, nem sempre é boa referência, especialmente em assuntos desse tipo onde não tem muita formalização, lá há muita especulação, mas é uma referência que pode ser usada para ter uma ideia, só não tome como verdade. [Ela coloca Assembly como baixo nível](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language).

Não fala especificamente de C ser, mas [o nível seguinte falado lá é o alto nível](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language). Não tem médio nível.

O que existe é um nível maior ainda, [o mais alto nível](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_high-level_programming_language) (que é o único lugar que eu já vi falar nisso), e parece estabelecer que linguagens de *script* são assim. E isso acaba sendo um problema porque essas linguagens, ao contrário das DSLs onde o termo teria iniciado, não tem nada muito mais abstrato que outras linguagens, e essas mesmas linguagens tem tentado mudar sua filosofia.

Usei isso para tentar mostrar que não tem uma boa definição, não para mostrar que C é baixo ou médio nível, ninguém sabe ao certo e pouco importa, assim como importa menos ainda de que geração a linguagem é. E pra mim a definição de "mais alto nível" é o mesmo das linguagens de 5ª geração, ou seja, tem muita bobagem nisso.

#### Tentando dar níveis para as linguagens

Podemos dizer que a linguagem é de alto nível quando ela está próxima do entendimento humano. Eu mostro Python para algumas pessoas e elas dizem que estão vendo russo misturado com grego. Eu mostro C para qualquer **programador** e eles entendem o que tem ali, ainda que precise da explicação de um ou outro ponto de sintaxe. Isso não acontece com Assembly. Então C é bem compreensível para um humano com conhecimento real sobre programação.

O mesmo código escrito completamente em C++ pode ser menos compreensível por ter abstração demais, ainda que todos concordem que está mais expressivo e por isso estaria mais em alto nível.

Outra definição diz que a linguagem precisa acessar o hardware mais diretamente. Isso faz C ser mais baixo nível? Assembly permite exatamente o mesmo nível. C# é quase o mesmo. Estão todos estão no mesmo ou quase mesmo nível?

C prefere que você programador crie suas abstrações em vez de entregar elas prontas. E ela não dá muitos mecanismos para criar abstrações que ficam imperceptíveis. Mas ela é muito diferente de ser completamente concreta. Então o médio talvez venha daí.

Mas como ficaria C++? Ela permite e entrega muito mais abstração, evita você cuidar do irrelevante. Mas ela permite fazer o mais concreto, gerenciar cada detalhe, até por ser bastante compatível com C. Então C++ é o que?

E Rust?

Java e principalmente C# permitem quase tudo que C permite, mas entrega um jeito padrão mais abstrato e controlado.

Linguagens de *script* são mais alto nível então? Já viu Perl? Ninguém entende aquilo.

COBOL teria um nível muito alto por ser tão verbosa?

## Conclusão

Antes de classificar linguagens pelo seu nível precisamos achar um consenso do que é cada nível e isso nem existe.

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57325/101) tem uma referência de onde saiu o tal médio nível. Qualquer um pode escrever o que quiser, o papel e o HTML aceitam tudo. Só porque alguém no Rio Grande do Sul ou outro lugar escreveu que ela é médio nível, não quer dizer que seja. Pelo menos a citação usada é bem confusa, não parece que a pessoa sabe o que está dizendo e ela não explica aquilo.

Eu não vou explicar o que eu nem concordo que seja verdade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, Os dizeres relatados como "nível médio" , é com certeza uma figura de linguagem empregada por alguém ou alguns rs.. Mais há alguns pontos que pra mim fazem estes dizeres terem algum sentido.. Exemplos:

1. Pelas linguagens que já estudei até então, acredito que a linguagem C é a com menos camadas de abstrações até o *código* chegar de fato no processador
2. A questão do software Hex_Rays Decompiler chama bastante atenção também.. por
   conta do pseudocode C que é gerado ao usarmos o software para decompilar um binário.

***O ponto aqui é*** :
A lógica do programa que foi decompilado só consegue ser representado pela linguagem C ( mesmo sendo um pseudocode ). Ou melhor é mais fácil ser representado pela C lang  por conta das construções e grandezas da linguagem C serem bem compatíveis com a forma em que algoritmos de baixo nível(assembly) trabalham.

PS : Essa é uma conclusão MINHA com base no meu raso conhecimento em C e pela prática que já tive com reversing e decompilers..